# Definition o branched 1-manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, definitions

i'm studying a papper which has this term "branched 1-manifolds", but the papper does not explain this, according to Wikipédia:

> "A finite graph whose edges are smoothly embedded arcs in a surface, such that all edges incident to a given vertex v have the same tangent line at v, is a branched one-manifold.  "

But i do not understand this definition. Someone could help me?

Comment: What part do you not understand?

Comment: "A finite graph whose edges are smoothly embedded arcs in a surface.." How i can see this formally?

Comment: [Cross-posted to math.SE.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1441050/definition-of-a-branched-1-manifold)

Answer (score 3):

A picture is worth a thousand words.

[image]

Comment: I still did not understand. :(